# solving network connection problem on xp

Tags: networking, lan

I feel so stupid, because I have to fix my dad computer(which was mine years ago).

So it is an old computer on which I have installed windows xp and the drivers for main-board. The device manager says that I have no more problems with the hardware. That computer has to connect to a router from my room but it doesn't. On ping 192.168.2.1 I get "Request time out"., The other computers are connecting to that router. Only the old computer doesn't connect to the LAN and later to the internet.

Also it doesn't get a good IP(from the same class). After running ipconfig command I know that i have an IP with 169....

What can I do? Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score 2):

The 169... address is what's known as an APIPA (Automatic Private IP Addressing) assignment, which basically means that your computer was unable to find a DHCP server (the router?) so it automatically assigns itself an address.

I'd check the cabling, if wired. If wireless make sure your WEP/WPA security settings are correct and make sure you're not blocking connections for that computer at the router.

As a quick test, to see if you have any connectivity, you could manually assign an IP Address to the computer, from the range you're using on your LAN. If, once configured, you can see other devices on the LAN, it probably points at the router not being able to assign a new address.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pulse's answer, also check if the router may not be rejecting the connection because MAC filtering is on or other security measure.